# Delphi FMX, change TComboBox images at runtime

Tags: delphi, combobox, firemonkey, imagelist

If I programmatically change TComboBox.Images to a new TImageList, only the selected icon in the TComboBox changes, all other icons in the TComboBox (drop-down list) remain the same.

I have two TImageLists, one with color icons and one with black and white icons and I want to change the black and white icons to colored icons and vice versa.

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ComboBox1.Images = ImageList1 then
    ComboBox1.Images := ImageList2
  else
    ComboBox1.Images := ImageList1;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Appears like a FMX bug.

Comment: Trivia: surprisingly many of those slovenian words are understandable for a German with basic English skills, even "nič" ("nix"). Seems to be just a coincidence tho.

Comment: These are transport types and the words are similar in many languages.

Comment: Yes, it really appears to be a bug in FMX.

Comment: I noticed that if you change the ImageList before clicking on the ComboBox, the icons change. Once you click on the ComboBox (to expand it) the icons in the drop down menu don't change anymore.

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: What happens if you expand the list, close it and then attempt to change the images, while the dropdown is closed. I'm trying to ask whether the problem persists forever once you have expanded or whether the problem occurs only *while expanded*

Comment: I can confirm the issue in Delphi 10.4 CE. The imagelist can be changed before the first dropdown, then after the images in the dropdown do not change anymore. When not dropped down, the image visible for the selected item change when the imagelist is changed.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Delphi 10.4 CE Update 2 and you're right. The imagelist can be changed before the first dropdown, then after the images in the dropdown do not change anymore. When not dropped down, the image visible for the selected item change when the imagelist is changed.

Comment: I tested your code with TComboBoxEx with delphi 10.3 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the question comments this is indeed a bug in Delphi as the internal drop down list is not refreshed when changing the `Images` property after showing the popup at least one time. This can be corrected by making a small change in the `FMX.ListBox.pas` source file at `TCustomComboBox.SetImages` procedure:

For Delphi 11:

```
procedure TCustomComboBox.SetImages(const Value: TCustomImageList);
begin
  FImageLink.Images := Value;
  FItemsChanged := True;        // <- Add this
end;
```

For Delphi 10.4 CE:

```
procedure TCustomComboBox.SetImages(const Value: TCustomImageList);
begin
  FImageLink.Images := Value;
  TComboBoxHelper.SetItemsChanged(Self, True);        // <- Add this
end;
```

Comment: Hello,
I have Delphi 10.4 Community Edition and I don't know if I can fix the source code at all.
Even if I change the source code and recompile, your fix doesn't work.

Comment: @sax I've added a workaround specific for Delphi 10.4 CE as the source is quite different, also remember that you must copy the source file from the installation folder to your project folder and change that file.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Your solution works on Delphi 10.4!
It works like charm!